# Error when trying to insert values in Postgres query inside Bash script

Tags: bash, postgresql, sql-insert

I'm executing the query as follows:

```
ssh user@XX.XX.1XX.XX "PGPASSWORD=myPassword psql -U psqlUser -h XX.XX.XX.XX -p 5432 -d myDB -c
'INSERT INTO table(\"CPU_IDLE_TIME\",\"TOTAL_SIZE\",\"USED_SIZE\",\"USED_STORAGE_P\") VALUES ($idlecputime,$totalSize,$usedSize,$usedStoragePercentage)';"
```

I obtain the values previous to this query doing snmpwalks. In order for the query to work the values have to be surrounded by single quotes (' '). I tried putting single quotes around the variable but everytime I get an error because the query is already surroundes by " ' ' ". I can't seem to find the configuration of quotes, or scaping quotes to make it work.

The variables are of type var char, integer and float.

One of the errores I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `printf` to format the string for you

```
ssh user@XX.XX.1XX.XX "PGPASSWORD=myPassword psql -U psqlUser -h XX.XX.XX.XX -p 5432 -d myDB -c ""$(printf 'INSERT INTO table("CPU_IDLE_TIME","TOTAL_SIZE","USED_SIZE","USED_STORAGE_P") VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d);' $idlecputime $totalSize $usedSize $usedStoragePercentage)"
```

The $( ) construct executes printf in a subshell.

Comment: This did work. But I just ended up installing a postgres client on this server to make things easier. Thanks!