# How can I insert the content of the variable into single quotes inside the INSERT INTO command?

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, csv

I created a text file. The name of this is "test.txt" and the content is first part below. I also created script with the name `insert.sh`. 
I run the command with `./insert.sh test.txt`.

If the words / strings are in single quotes, it will insert the words into the columns. Also it will insert numbers without single quotes. The csv that I will eventually use won't have single quotes and I don't want to change the data.

How can I insert the content of the variable into single quotes inside the `INSERT INTO` command?

I am using psql.

Text file, test.txt

```
'one','ten','hundred'
'two','twenty','twohundred'
```

Script, insert.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read cell
do
    name=$cell
    echo "$cell"

####Insert from txt into table####
sudo -u username -H -- psql -d insert_test -c "
INSERT INTO first (ten, hundred, thousend) VALUES ($cell);
"
done < $1
```

something like this:

```
INSERT INTO first (ten, hundred, thousend) VALUES (INSERT" $cell "QUOTES);
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed the code. I added the single quotes around $cell as you suggested.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read cell
do
    name=$cell
    echo "$cell"

####Insert from txt into table####
sudo -u username -H -- psql -d insert_test -c "
INSERT INTO first (ten, hundred, thousend) VALUES ('$cell');
"
done < $1
```

and I removed the quotes out of the text file since the csv file that I want to use later wont have any single quotes.

new text file.
one,ten,hundred 
two,twenty,twohundred

and im getting the error:

one,two,three

```
ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions
LINE 2: INSERT INTO first (ten, hundred, thousend) VALUES ('one,two,...
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample line from test.txt?

Comment: Yep, accidentally deleted that when it was re-formatted.  I want to run it without single quotes in the text file.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52939449/2834978).

Comment: Note that `printf` won't protect you against SQL injection.

Comment: How would I use printf in this context? If anyone can suggest an answer that would be great, even if just a tentative idea.

Comment: what if your text file was: `one','ten','hundred two','twenty','twohundred`? But the errors seems to point out, that your cell reading is problematic. Because you are getting `one,two,three` instead of what I expected to be `one,hundred,thousend`.

Comment: I didn't use that same text file but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the `$IFS` ([Internal Field Separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)) variable to determine the line separator used by Bash. Since you used a CSV like file, you `IFS` come to `,` character, thus this is the result `$IFS=,`. Note that if you need to do others stuff in you script, you need to redefine the `$IFS` var to the original state, so you need to store it in an temportal variable **before** you change it, something like `$OLDIFS=$IFS`.

`readline` read the entire line and separate the values depending on `$IFS` var, thus you need to write the adecauted quantity of var where `readline` will store the words, i.e., if you line have 3 words, you need to give 3 vars to `readline`, e.g.: file: `foo,baz,bar`, `readline -r word1 word2 word3`. If you don't give the correct amount of vars, `readline` will store the rest of word in a single var, that is your problem.

So, a solution to your problem would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
$OLDIFS=$IFS # If you need to do more stuff.

while IFS=, read -r word1 word2 word3
do
  sudo -u username -H -- psql -d insert_test -c
  "INSERT INTO first (ten, hundred, thousend) VALUES (${word1}, ${word2}, ${word3});"
done < $1

$IFS=$OLDIFS # Same of line 2.
# ...
```

**NOTE**: This is ***insecure*** because lead with easily to a SQL injection. If you use this, only use in a local database that don't have any sensetive data.